# Failure to disable animations: cmd: Failure calling service settings: Broken pipe (32)

Tags: android, bash, azure-devops, android-emulator, adb

This is an issue that keeps happening on my remote builds using Azure Devops, less then 10% of the time but often enough to be a problem. After successfully starting three Android emulators, I run a bash script:

```
echo "Disable animations"
adb devices | awk 'NR>1 && /emulator/ {print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
adb devices | awk 'NR>1 && /emulator/ {print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0
adb devices | awk 'NR>1 && /emulator/ {print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0.0
adb devices | awk 'NR>1 && /emulator/ {print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0.0

echo "Verifying animation is disabled"
adb devices | awk 'NR>1 && /emulator/ {print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % shell settings get global window_animation_scale
```

Far more times than I would like, it fails with errors that look like this:

```
Disable animations
cmd: Failure calling service settings: Broken pipe (32)
cmd: Can't find service: settings
cmd: Can't find service: settings
Verifying animation is disabled
0.0
cmd: Can't find service: settings
0.0
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

I don't know what this means and I don't know what's happening, let alone how to fix it.

Comment: What kind of agent are you using? Can you try to run the command; `adb shell service list ` and check if settings exists in the output?

Comment: It isn't happening every time, just often enough to be an issue worth investigating. Definitely <10% of the time. I could add the command to the script before it tries to to disable animations and see if it's any different on the builds that fail.